# How to create column in a table which takes values from another table when the condition is met but assigns a different value if condition fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table for eg: Table 1 which has a column containing dates and another column containing some numeric value related to that date. It is having random dates between 1-jan-2018 to 31-dec-2018. 
I'm trying to create another table with similar structure (2 fields date and numeric value), but the date should have entries for all days of 2018,and in the 2nd column should have '-1' for the dates that were not present in the 1st table, and the numeric value from 1st table if the dates match.

----This gives me the dates in the second table ---

```
;WITH CTE AS




(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1 AS [Incrementor]
  FROM   [master].[sys].[columns] sc1
  CROSS JOIN [master].[sys].[columns] sc2
)




SELECT DATEADD(DAY, cte.[Incrementor], '2018-01-01') as [date]
into [Table 2]

FROM CTE 

WHERE DATEADD(DAY, cte.[Incrementor], '2018-01-01') < '2018-12-31'
```

Then I used case statement to generate column 2 in table 2 but did not succeed.

```
select [Table 2].[date],
case
when ([Table 2].[date] = [table 1].[date] 

then [Table1].[numericvalue] else '-1')

end as [NewNumericValue]

from 
[Table1] 

inner join

[table2]

on [table 1].[date] = [table 2].[date]
```

[Table 2 Date column has all dates in 2018.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFbar.jpg)

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful

Comment: Also what have you tried so far. SO aims to help but not write code. That sound s like an exercise from coursework.

Comment: This is an interview question. Not any coursework.

Comment: @Jk_Bose Interview quesion/homework question, either way you should be trying first. Those using their free time to help you arent here to help you get a job or get good grades. Without offence, if you can't answer an interview quesion yourself, are you suited for the role? Show us your answer and we can tell you what we think on it, but we're not the ones being Interviewed; you are

Comment: @Larnu Apologies.Quite new to posting questions in Stack Overflow. I have added what I have tried.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. One helpful item is to include a _question_, not just a requirements document.

Comment: You're just not ready. You figured out how to create a table of sequential dates. That's the big hurdle. Now outer join that to your Table1. The columns to include are the date from your calendar table and an expression that checks for a null in the value column and swaps it for -1. This can all be done in a single statement.

Comment: @SMor Thank you. It helped me to arrive at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS

(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1 AS [Incrementor]
  FROM   [master].[sys].[columns] sc1
  CROSS JOIN [master].[sys].[columns] sc2
)

select [date],isnull([Numericvalue],-1) from 
(SELECT DATEADD(DAY, cte.[Incrementor], '2018-01-01') as [date]
FROM CTE 
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, cte.[Incrementor], '2018-01-01')<'2018-12-31') as Table2    
left join
[Table1]
on [Table2].[date] = [Table1].[date]
```

Comment: can you tell me how to fetch top x within the select of the cte query